# Add prefix to Angular dev servers url

Tags: javascript, angular, server

In prod our application will not be severed from the root, it will be server something like ***https://ourdomain.com/ourapp***

This is causing issues with image urls so I would like to serve from the dev server ***http://localhost:4200/ourapp*** but cannot find a way to configure the dev server to app a prefix to the url. Is this possible?

Comment: Try proxy config

Comment: But for api call you can set it as a local environment

Comment: try changing the `<base href="/">` to `<base href="ourdomain">`

Answer (score 3):

In Angular 6 you can config that in the "angular.json"
Take a look at  the documentation at
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/angular-cli
there is an option "baseHref" that will do the trick.

Important:
In your index.html you have to set

```
<base href="/">
```

Angular will change that in the build/serve process to the url you had configured.

warm regards

Comment: Unfortunately our security team haven't added Angular 6 to our internal node repository yet. We are suck on 5.2.

Comment: This is for the build, I am looking to add ourapp in the url of the local development server.

Comment: We use that option also for our local development (webpack) server